# Why isn't the registry key value getting created?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer-8, regedit, registrykey

I did the below coding.But when I execute it, the registry key entry is not created even though no exceptions are thrown:

```
  Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
        key=Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main");

        key=Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main",true);
        key.SetValue("TabProcGrowth", "20");
        key.Close();
```

Comment: It works for me. Could it be a permissions issue? Where are you looking for the key? It goes under Wow6432Node on my machine.

Comment: I forgot the Wow6432Node thanks! its there.